# how display and hide image view

Tags: android

if you look at the picture
http://store3.up-00.com/Nov12/MYo64560.png

it display a list of student each with calculate button

after click to the calculate button the system will do 
some Calculation if the sum is more than 10 so it display Near to the student 
a red Circle 
else nothing happened 
knowing that i use an adapter

my question how display the image which is in method getview
after do the calcaultion which is in Calculations

also if i think about redCircle change without click i want to change automatically

and thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
ImageView redCircleView;

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

holder.redCircle = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.redCircle);// for red Circle
redCircleView = holder.redCircle; 
StudentID = student.get(holder.position).get(StudentID); // get id for the student
and i have 
new Calculations().execute();//do some Calculations which i will do the Calculation  the sum
}
```

You need to implement onProgressUpdate within the Async (standard source -> override and implement) etc. and then use publishProgress() method which will call the onProgress and do whatever you've got there.

```
if ((sum) >= 10) {
publishProgress("addPic");
                    }
```

Then also have this

```
@Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
if(values[0].contentEquals("addPic"){
redCircleView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
}
```

Comment: so you mean that onProgress do the calcaultion right ? but i did not understand what do you mean about publishProgress() how can i call it and get if the sum >10 or not and the display or hide imgeview

Comment: Basically where you have the sum line already in your code, add my line publishProgress("addPic"); which will automatically call it when your sum is higher than 10. Then where I've sad add your code to add pic here, put code to display your imageview

Comment: thanks but the image is in get-view method  holder.redCircle = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.redCircle); so how to hide it or diaply it depend in publishProgress // for red Circle

Comment: If you add more code above then we will see why it's not working. Have you added the redcircle in a layout in XML?

Comment: To make it hide it's the same command with View.INVISIBLE published in your else bracket

Comment: can i use any method in imageview so the image is depend in function without said onclick

Comment: Where is the onclick? Best to ask another question posting your new code, otherwise no space to answer. Don't forget to accept an answer :)